# PHP/SQLite with multiple SQL statements: $db->Query() works, $this->db_sqlite->query() fails

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, oop

I am creating a class that handles various SQLite actions. My problem is: When I make a SQL string with multiple statements then it works when using standard PHP => $db->query() ... but it fails when making the same request from a method. It seems that the OO method skips everything after the first ";"-symbol in my SQL statement. Why is that, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

```
// Fails - line 2 is not inserted, why?
$this->db_sqlite->query("
    INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class multi-lines 1');
    INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class multi-lines 2');
");

// Works - both lines are inserted.
$GLOBALS[db]->query("
    INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Direct multi-lines 1');
    INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Direct multi-lines 2');
");
```

Full example:

```
<?php

class db_sqlite {

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function connect() {
        $GLOBALS[db] = new SQLiteDatabase("dbsqlite.php.db");
    }

    function query($sql) {
        return $GLOBALS[db]->query($sql);
    }

}


class something {

    function setup() {
        $this->db_sqlite = new db_sqlite();

        $this->db_sqlite->query("CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name CHAR(255) );");

        // Works
        $this->db_sqlite->query("INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class one line 1');");
        $this->db_sqlite->query("INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class one line 2');");

        // Fails (why?)
        $this->db_sqlite->query("
            INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class multi-lines 1');
            INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Via class multi-lines 2');
        ");

        // Works
        $GLOBALS[db]->query("
            INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Direct multi-lines 1');
            INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES('Direct multi-lines 2');
        ");

        foreach($this->db_sqlite->query("SELECT * FROM foo") as $v) {
            echo $v[id] . " - " . $v[name] ."<br>";
        }
    }
}

$something = new something();
$something->setup();
?>
```

Output:
1 - Via class one line 1 (correct)
2 - Via class one line 2 (correct)
3 - Via class multi-lines 1 (incorrect)
4 - Direct multi-lines 1 (correct)
5 - Direct multi-lines 2 (correct)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP manual page for [sqlite_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php) says, about using multiple statements in one function call, "...this works only when the result of the function is not used - if it is used, only the first SQL statement would be executed." Since you're returning the result, you're "using" it. That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This will fire multiple queries (returns no results): $GLOBALS[db]->queryExec($sql) ... and it also works as a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an errorMsg holder variable that will be set if any error occur. It could be a good idea to check if sqlite returns anything there:

syntax:
query  ( string $query  [, int $result_type  [, string &$error_msg  ]] )

$result_type could be SQLITE_BOTH (default)